# Notification disappear after activity finish

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-notifications

I have an activity named `A` which start from a `broadcast receiver`. Activity `A` triggered a notification but it disappear automatically when activity destroy(finish). But I want to keep this notification until the user click or manually clear the notification.

## How activity start from broadcast receiver

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,A.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
context.startActivity(i);
```

## Notification

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
notificationIntent.setClass(context,B.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small)
        .setContentTitle(status)
        .setTicker(status)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setLargeIcon(
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();
```

## manifest options

```
<activity android:name="com.example.activity.A"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:taskAffinity=""
android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

**Note: I also tried singleInstance but no luck.**

## Edit(Fixed)

I made a silly mistake. I called clearAll() instead of cancel a specific notification in onDestroy() function.

Comment: do you cancel notification somewhere using  mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);?

Comment: see I mentioned that in my comment that you are clearing the notification

Answer (score 3):

I think you are cancelling all the notification in your app when the activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

remove autocancel() totally and try this,

```
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;


    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle(" ").
                                            setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bundle.get("").toString())).
                                            setContentText(bundle.get("").toString());
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I exactly copy your code. But situation is same. Notification appear but clear when activity finish

Comment: i tested it and woking ,  have you verified that you are not cancel the notification in somewhere ?